# How to write (edit) long label text in kv file?

Tags: python, text, label, kivy

How should I write a long text (> 80 chars) relating to a Label in a .kv file?
For example:

```
Label:
    Text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \
           Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis \
           natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.'
```

This example generates errors. I have tried all kinds of formats nor can I find a solution in the forums.

Comment: Assignments to properties must be on one line, and cannot be extended with newline escapes. Cf https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html

Comment: OK. Didn't read this paragraph. Thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [assignments toproperties must be on one line](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#valid-expressons), they can certainly contain more than 80 characters. Another option is to define the text in a python file and import it into the `kv` file.

Example:

```
#:import fix fixtures
<Label>:
    text_size: (self.parent.width, self.height)
    width: self.parent.width

GridLayout:
    rows: 2
    Label:
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.'
    Label:
        text: fix.text
```

`fixtures.py`:

```
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque \
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I will use this.